Unable to get 'IsPrimaryIpv6' field from "ec2-describe-network-interfaces" method in AWS CLI
I need to detach IPv6 addresses from one interface to attach to another, and since one of these addresses is the primary IPv6, I get the error message that I can't detach a primary address. However, in the output for ec2-describe-network-interfaces, the key 'IsPrimaryIpv6' is missing under 'Ipv6Addresses' (even though the it's present in the documentation here.
Are there alternative methods to get this information, or ways to modify my configuration to get this information from describe-network-interfaces?
I get a key error when I try to access ['IsPrimaryIpv6'] from the array of Ipv6Addresses.
